# Delete where in does not works

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, sql-delete

I m working in a project with a Postres DB.
I m trying to delete all rows of a table based on a python list.

My code is :

```
listofMonths = []
listofMonths = pl.month.unique() # list of months in which there is data to update
deletequery =  f'DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE month IN (' + ','.join((str(n) for n in listofMonths)) + ');'
db.execute(deletequery)
```

I have an error :
Deleted error into table plc (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 1: DELETE FROM plc WHERE month IN (2020-03-0...
                                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

month column is a text one.

my query seems to be like that :
'DELETE FROM plclass123145722922162 WHERE month IN (2020-03-01,2020-01-01,2020-02-01,2020-04-01);'

I m sure that I need ' between values but don t know to fix that

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose `n` in a pair of single quotes when outputting it:

```
deletequery =  f'DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE month IN (' + ','.join(f"'{n}'" for n in listofMonths) + ');'
```

Comment: it seems not working  result is:'DELETE FROM plclass123145722922162 WHERE month IN (\'2020-03-01\',\'2020-01-01\',\'2020-02-01\',\'2020-04-01\');'

Comment: Did you make it an f-string? Note the `f` in `f"'{n}'"` in the example code above.

Comment: this is my code: f'DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE month IN (' + ','.join(f"'{n}'" for n in listofMonths) + ');'

Comment: The expanded string in your updated comment above looks correct to me. What is the behavior now? Is it producing an error or is it simply returning no matching row at all?

Comment: hi sorry for late answer. seems working well thanks :-)